# Accessing counts associated to each elements

Tags: python, list, counter

If a have a list of elements with theirs counts as below

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2),('d', 3), ('e', 3)]
```

And now I want to find out how many of them appear once,twice,and three times.
So the expected output would be something like

```
1:1,2:2,3:2
```

The list is generated by the `Counter` function `Counter(lst)`

Answer (score 1):

Use another `Counter` on the `values` of your first `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'abbccdddeee'
c = Counter(s)
counts = Counter(c.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`collections.Counter`** again but this time count second element in each tuple.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2),('d', 3), ('e', 3)]

print(Counter(x[1] for x in lst))   # x[1] takes second element from each tuple.
# Counter({2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1})
```